# Marshalling exceptions across threads (without a SynchronizationContext)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, exception, blockingcollection

I have an event handler that's calling a method synchronously.

```
void OnSomeEventHappened(int eventInfo)
{
    MethodDoingSomething(eventInfo);
}
```

I want to change this event handler so that the method call (to MethodDoingSomething) becomes asynchronous.

The problem is that MethodDoingSomething might throw an exception and it is important that in the new asynchronous behavior these exceptions continue to be thrown from the thread in which the event Handler is running (i.e. the original thead that used to receive the exception in the synchronous case).

I also need the calls to be executed in the same order that they arrive.

My approach is to use a blocking collection to implement a FIFO task queue.

```
void OnSomeEventHappened(int eventInfo)
{
    _blockingCollectionFifoQueue.Add(eventInfo);
}
```

And there is a consumer of the blocking collection that calls the original method:

```
void RunConsumer()
{
    foreach (var elem in _blockingCollectionFifoQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        MethodDoingSomething(elem);
    }
}
```

In that scenario, how do I get the exceptions that might be thrown from MethodDoingSomething and rethrow them in the main thread as they were before when the code was synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to re-throw the exception in the event handler as in your synchronous scenario, because - since we're now asynchronous - we cannot tell which method runs on that thread where `OnSomeEventHappened` executed when we want to throw.

However, you can post an exception on that thread's `SynchronizationContext`, if there is any.

If your `OnSomeEventHappened` event handler runs on the UI thread of a WPF or a WinForms application, there will be a `SychronizationContext` you can use.

If it's a random or a thread pool thread - that means there is no `SynchronizationContext` on that thread - you will have to write your own implementation of that (**hint:** don't, it's a hard thing to implement correctly). To trigger something on a different thread, you need some kind of synchronization or messaging system.

If you want to re-throw the exceptions on the same thread all the times, you can store the synchronization context of the target thread and use this reference:

```
// Make sure this code is executed on the thread that will receive the exceptions.
// Note that 'Current' will be null for thread pool threads
this.exceptionsSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

Then, your blocking collection processing could look like this:

```
try
{
    MethodDoingSomething(elem);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Capture the exception into an ExceptionDispatchInfo so that its 
    // stack trace and Watson bucket info will be preserved
    var edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
    this.exceptionsSyncContext.Post(state => ((ExceptionDispatchInfo)state).Throw(), edi);
}
```

If you want to re-throw your exceptions on different threads, just store the corresponding `SynchronizationContext` references in the same collection along with your `eventInfo`. E.g. use a tuple for that.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I don't have a SynchronizationContext (my thread is the main thread of a windows service). So I guess my question boils down to finding the synchronization or messaging system that you alluded to in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
async Task RunConsumer()
{
    foreach (var elem in _blockingCollectionFifoQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        try
        {
            await MethodDoingSomethingAsync(elem);
        }
        catch (MyException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This way exceptions from MethodDoingSomethingAsync will be handled in the catch block inside the foreach loop. It already works out of the box.

In debugging mode, you will probably get a user unhandled exception message. You will need to disable it or run the program without debugging to see the correct result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The exception thrown in RunConsumer is not propagated to the main thread. Plus the foreach loop is exited after the throw which is not what I want.

Comment: Well to solve the second issue, you will need to collect the exceptions somewhere and throw an AggregateException after the loop finished. If you don't want that, Exceptions are probably not the best way to handle errors here.